# Can I delete "au fait" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire

I came across the following sentence in an interview I am reading in a magazine:

> Cela m'a initié **au fait** que la sexualité peut être très amusante et sécuritaire.

I figured out that "au fait" is not an interjection, but instead the construction is "initié à + le fait que [...]", where "fait" is a noun that means "fact".

But still, if I deleted "au fait" as if it was an interjection, the English translation still makes sense:

> Cela m'a initié que la sexualité peut être très amusante et sécuritaire.
>   *(This taught me that sexuality can be very fun and of-security)*

But I am unsure if I'm allowed to do this.

Question:
Is

> Cela m'a initié que la sexualité peut être très amusante et sécuritaire.

a correct sentence?

Comment: [*Sécuritaire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9curitaire) is odd here, should rather be *amusante et sûre*. You sentence might have been *Cela m'a appris que la sexualité...*

Comment: [deleted -- this was meant for the answer below!]

Comment: @silph Your second quote is incorrect. *Initier* does **not** translate to *teach*, nor is *initiate* an equivalent for *teach* in English (they have different objects).

Comment: @guillaume31 I got the meaning of "to teach" from http://www.wordreference.com/fren/initier

Comment: Unlike *teach someone that ... *, *initiate someone that ...* is not grammatically correct in English. It's exactly the same in French.

Comment: If you're going to use a dictionary to translate *teach* into an *initier*-compatible form, you should follow its indications. `teach [sb] [sth]` => initier `[qqun] à [qqch]` (and not `que [qqch]`). In French, the object is not the thing that is taught.

Comment: @guillaume31 "not `que [qqch]` was exactly why I was suspecting that deleting "au fait" might be incorrect, but I wasn't sure. [I am new to using a French-English dictionary and following its indications]. That's the main reason I opened up this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to use it.

*Initier* doesn't behave like *apprendre*, it's closer to *introduce (to something)*, both in meaning and grammar. It's supposed to be used for a wide subject, not something very precise.

> Il m'a initié à la philosophie.
>
> Je suis allé à cours d'initiation au tir à l'arc.

*Initier* is always transitive, so you always have to use "*Initier* ***à***". Using *au fait que* is a workaround to use *initier* instead of *apprendre*, to convey the idea of "*gently dipping into a subject*", but they're not really synonyms.

---

In the same way, you can't say "*malgré que*" (despite the fact that a lot of people say it), like in English actually: *despite* must be followed by a noun, so you have to transform your subordinate sentence ("*a lot of people say it*") to be a noun, and you do that by adding "*the fact that*".

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. "au fait" is needed here.
"initier" can be 'transitif' - it is the case here, it takes the meaning "to be taught" ; or 'intransitif', it then takes the meaning "to begin"

Comment: The wordreference on initier seems to indicate that initier is *never* intransitive; that is it only transitive? http://www.wordreference.com/fren/initier

Comment: I wonder why "apprendre que" is okay, but "initier que" is not? I would have thought that a dictionary would tell me this? Oh well. This leads, now, to a more complicated question that I might write up tomorrow, about when I'm allowed to use "que" as a conjunction, and when I'm not!

Comment: A method I sometimes use to figure out if a construction is valid in some language is querying google books, e.g. : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%27ai+initi%C3%A9+que%2Cj%27ai+appris+que&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cj%27ai%20appris%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bj%27ai%20appris%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJ%27ai%20appris%20que%3B%2Cc0 (Using that link, you might have to click again on the "Search lots of books" button to get results)